# Space of functionals

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $\hat{S} = k[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ and let $\hat{S}^\vee = \text{Hom}_k(\hat{S},k)$ where $k$ is a field.

In general, if we have a vector space $V$ over $k$, then there is a natural pairing $\langle -,- \rangle: V \times V^\vee \to k$ given by $\langle v,f \rangle \mapsto f(v)$.

In the case above, I just cant seem to figure out how this would work. How does the elements in the space of functionals $\hat{S}^\vee$ look like? I thought of them as elements $f_x: k[[x_1,...,x_n]] \to k$ defined by $g \mapsto g(x)$ where $g \in k[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ and $x \in k$. Is this correct? It struck me that $g(x)$ may not even be in $k$ for $g = x_1 + x^2_1 + x^3_1 + ...$.

my interpretation feels wrong, indeed the author of my compendium seems to think of the elements in $\hat{S}^\vee$ as polynomial expressions?

Can someone help to clarify on this please.

Comment: The morphisms of $\widehat{S}^{\vee}$ are morphisms of $k$-algebras or $k$-vector spaces ?

Comment: @Tuvasbien the morphisms are referred to  "the space of functionals". I guess they can be regarded as both $k$-vector space morphisms and $k$-algebra morphisms. Im trying to figure out if that matters, but im not sure..

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f:\widehat{S}\longrightarrow k$ is morphism of $k$-vector spaces, a $k$-basis of $\widehat{S}$ is $(x_1^{i_1},\ldots,x_n^{i_n})_{i_1,\ldots,i_n\geqslant 0}$ so $f$ is uniquely defined by its values at each $x_k^{i_k}$. If $f:\widehat{S}\longrightarrow k$ is a morphism of $k$-algebras, then it is uniquely defined by its values at $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. For each $x\in k^n$, let ${\rm ev}_x:\widehat{S}\longrightarrow k$ be the evaluation morphism at $x$, that is ${\rm ev}_x(g)=g(x)$, then one sees that $f={\rm ev}_{(f(x_1),\ldots f(x_n))}$. In this case, this means that we have a natural pairing $\widehat{S}^{\vee}\times\widehat{S}\longrightarrow k$ defined by $({\rm ev}_x,g)\mapsto g(x)$, or equivalently, $(f,g)\mapsto g(f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n))$.